# CoreData, UIImage and Unwrapping

Tags: swift, image, uikit, uiimage

My app needs to display an image pulled from a CoreData entity with 2 levels of fallback should the attribute be nil. First, it looks at the Entity.bannerImageBlob attribute (binary data/external storage) and tries to build a UIImage from that. If that fails it looks in the asset catalog for an asset named Entity.bannerImageName, and if that doesn't exist, it uses "banner-placeholder", which exists in the asset catalog.

Because instantiating a UIImage can fail and has to be unwrapped, and because core data attributes are all optional, I am getting into a bit of an if-pyramid/unwrapping loop such that it seems like I am going about this inelegantly.

(Some of this complication is a result of migrating from storing images in the asset catalog to storing them in CoreData/filesystem, but I need to make sure I can communicate between all of these schemes.)

Here's the convenience var from my Entity Extension for CoreData. Entity Attributes have a trailing underscore. This is how I would like it to work (this code does not work).

```
var bannerImage: Image {
    let fallback = UIImage(named: bannerImageName_ ?? "banner-placeholder")
    
    if let blobImage = UIImage(data: bannerImageBlob_) { // error: data? must be unwrapped...
        return Image(uiImage: blobImage)
    } else {
        return Image(uiImage: fallback) // error: UIImage? must be unwrapped...
    }
}
```

This seems to create an endless cascade of coalescing default values. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why not use something like `return a ?? b ?? c`, that is return a if it is not nil otherwise return b if it is not nil else return c. Since the last image exists in your asset catalog you should be able to force unwrap it when calling Image(uiImage:)

Comment: How would that work in the context of UIImage? UIImage seems to need to be unwrapped even when called with a known-to-exist value.

Comment: See my updated comment, `UIImage(named: "banner-placeholder")!`

Comment: Totally. It still ends up like this: `return UIImage(data: bannerImageBlob_ ?? <#default value>) ?? UIImage(named: bannerImageName_ ?? <#default value>) ?? UIImage(named: "banner-placeholder")!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an extension to UIImage and add new factory methods that takes optional parameters

```
extension UIImage {
    static func create(data: Data?) -> UIImage? {
         guard let data = data else { return nil }
         return UIImage(data: data)
    }

    static func create(named: String?) -> UIImage? {
         guard let string = named else { return nil }
         return UIImage(named: string)
    }
}
```

And then

```
return UIImage.create(data: bannerImageBlog_) ??
    UIImage.create(named: bannerImageName_) ??
    UIImage(named: "banner-placeholder")!
```

Comment: Both work great. Filing away for use. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed missing return value declaration

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a more elegant solution, but you could simplify it into a single level of if-else statements:

```
var bannerImage: Image {
    if let data = bannerImageBlob_,
       let let blobImage = UIImage(data: data) {
        return Image(uiImage: blobImage)
    } else if let imageName = bannerImageName_,
              let image = UIImage(named: imageName) {
        return Image(uiImage: image)
    } else {
        let fallback = UIImage(named: "banner-placeholder")!
        return Image(uiImage: fallback)
    }
}
```

Instead of computing this every time, you may want to cache the images in memory, which might look something like this if you have a string `someUniqueId_` you can use as a key:

```
static fileprivate let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()

var bannerImage: Image {
    if let cachedImage = Self.imageCache.object(forKey: someUniqueId_) {
        return Image(uiImage: cachedImage)
    } else {
        let uiImage: UIImage = {
            if let data = bannerImageBlob_,
               let let blobImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                return blobImage
            } else if let imageName = bannerImageName_,
                      let image = UIImage(named: imageName) {
                return image
            } else {
                return UIImage(named: "banner-placeholder")!
            }
        }()
        Self.imageCache.setObject(uiImage, forKey: someUniqueId_)
        return Image(uiImage: uiImage)
    }
}
```